# htaccess rewrite - rules ignored?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have an API on my system, running on the domain "system.com", the api runs on "api.system.com", but is hosted on the same server.

The aim of my .htaccess is, to redirect all calls that contain "api.system.com", to my api folder, and all the others to my main site.

If there is no specific api requested (the REQUEST URI is empty) it should redirect to api/apidocs.php to show the apidocs.

The problem is, that even when I go to a valid url, it redirects me to api/apidocs.php.

Htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.system.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} json
RewriteRule (.+)\.json$ api/$1.php?type=json [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.system.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xml
RewriteRule (.+)\.xml$ api/$1.php?type=xml [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.system.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ api/apidocs.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^system.com
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test it, and there the code works.

I tried outputting the $_SERVER variable on api/apidocs.php, and there I get these (strange) variables:

```
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => C:/wamp/www/mysite/api/apidocs.php
[REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => type=json
[REDIRECT_URL] => /api/login.php
```

How can redirect_url and script_filename not be the same?

Answer (score 2):

Use this [httaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) for debugging. Maybe you could see what is failing.